# Trying to test run playbook. Getting permission denied

Tags: ssh, ansible, debian

I am trying to do a "dry-run" of a playbook. The machine I am targeting I am able to ssh into and vice versa. When I run the `ansible all -m ping -vvv` this is the output.

```
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/core/system/ping.py
<192.168.4.136> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: hwaraich207970
<192.168.4.136> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=username -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/username/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r 192.168.4.136 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1604952591.08-32914241935398 ` " && echo ansible-tmp-1604952591.08-32914241935398="` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1604952591.08-32914241935
398 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"'' 
192.168.4.136 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,password).\r\n",
    "unreachable": true
```

Answer (score 0):

This could happen even if you have made sure the passwordless ssh between System A and System B (say using either ssh-copy-id command or by manually copying the public key i.e content of the idrsa.pub file on System A to .ssh/authorizedkeys file on System B. If this is happening, one of the reason could be the user home directories.

On System A user home directory is say /home/tester and on System B, it is /users/tester, then passwordless ssh might not work. Make sure both users have the same home directory solves this issue. I observed this case in CentOS machines and on making sure the home directories for users same, the issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Ansible typically works when ssh public keys of the controller node are added to authorized keys of the remote node. This enables `ansible` to ssh into the remote node from the controlled node without the need for a password.

There is an alternate way to make ansible work without sharing public keys using `sshpass`. In this case, you need to input the password of the remote users via the `ansible_ssh_pass` variable.  This can be done via `inventory file`, `group_vars`, or the `extra-vars`.

Regarding the error shared by you. It says, "**Permission denied**", meaning there is something wrong related to either ssh key sharing or password setting.

```
msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,password).\r\n",
```

Debug mode provides more info related to the issue:

```
SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=username -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/username/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r 192.168.4.136 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1604952591.08-32914241935398 ` " && echo ansible-tmp-1604952591.08-32914241935398="` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1604952591.08-32914241935
```

Some relevant information you can extract from the above snippet:

1. `-o User=username`: This means playbook is trying to execute from `username` user ID.
2. `-o PasswordAuthentication=no`: This would force ansible to use public keys over password.
3. This authentication failure is happening for `192.168.4.136`.

Please check [this](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/connection_details.html) for official info regarding connections for ansible.
Check [this](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/copy-id) for generating and sharing ssh keys between the nodes.